# Não consigo instalar o pyautogui no python 3.7

Tags: pyautogui

Olá, pessoal! É o seguinte, tentei instalar o pyautogui no python 3.7 no linux mint e não estou conseguindo. Fiz todos os procedimentos do site oficial do pyautogui e de todos os outros blogs sobre o assunto tanto em português quando no inglês e nada feito! Alguém passou pelo mesmo problema e conseguiu resolver???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão `3.7` do `Python` ainda é bem recente e algumas ferramentas, bibliotecas e outros não possuem suporte para ela. Descobri na internet que essa versão vai ficar 100% no início de 2020. Por enquanto tente usar a versão 3.6 para utilizar suas libs e outros.

O `pyautogui` funciona perfeitamente na versão 3.6, mas é claro que daqui a algum tempo as coisas também começaram a funcionar na versão 3.7. É sempre bom se atualizar ;)

Answer (score -2):

Consegui a solução. Tive o mesmo problema, só que a minha versão do Python é 3.11, e o sistema operacional Windows 11. Uso o Visual Studio Code. Sou iniciante em Python e vivo perdendo a cancha. Quase desistindo justamente porque existe muita incompatibilidade com o sistema operacional e incompatibilidades com o próprio Python, e esses pacotes que parecem que não vão instalar de jeito nenhum.
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in...
Mas consegui resolver finalmente desinstalando o setuptools.
pip uninstall setuptools
Após isso, pip install pyautogui
Deu certo, finalmente!